# I want to know why my program is not stopping in my while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hy guys i have the following problem - Write a program to play the following simple game. The player starts with $100. On each
turn a coin is flipped and the player has to guess heads or tails. The player wins $9 for each
correct guess and loses $10 for each incorrect guess. The game ends either when the player
runs out of money or gets to $200.

My program is actually running. However when players points go bellow zero my program still runs and that is not what i expected. I need to know if there is something that i can do in my if sentences or if there is an easier way to make statements when i have to much conditions.

```
import random

list=['heads','tails']
def game():
    p1=100
    p2=100
    while (p1>0 or p2>0)and(p1<200 or p2<200):
        x=random.choice(list)
        x1=input('digit your guess player1 - ')
        x2=input('digit your guess player2 - ')
        if x1==x:
            p1+=30
        else:
            p1=p1-40
        if x2==x:
            p2+=30
        else:
            p2=p2-40
    return p1,p2
print(game())
```

I expect the program to return the scores and end if any player points goes above 200 or bellow 0

Comment: Why are there *two* players in your code?

Comment: This is a simple game i wanted the program to be more difficult

Comment: So when should the game end? When either player goes below 0 or when *both* of them do?

Comment: the program should stop if any player hits 0 or 200

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I consider your original problem, the problem is that you are returning whatever current value the player has, instead you should remember the last score and if the condition you want the game to stop on happens, return the last score. This will ensure only valid scores are returned

```
import random

list=['heads','tails']
def game():
    player=100
    last_score = 0

    #Conditions to break while loop
    while player > 0 and player < 200:

        #Keep track of last score
        last_score = player

        #Get choice from player, and increase/decrease score
        x=random.choice(list)
        x1=input('digit your guess player1 - ')
        if x1 == x:
            player += 9
        else:
            player -= 10

    #Return last score
    return last_score

print(game())
```

Extending this idea to the 2 player game will solve your issue as well!

```
import random

list=['heads','tails']

def game():
    p1=100
    p2=100
    last_scores = 0,0


    # Conditions to break while loop
    while (0<p1<200) and(0<p2<200):

        # Keep track of last score
        last_scores = p1,p2

        # Get choice from player, and increase/decrease score
        x=random.choice(list)
        x1=input('digit your guess player1 - ')
        x2=input('digit your guess player2 - ')

        if x1==x:
            p1+=30
        else:
            p1=p1-40
        if x2==x:
            p2+=30
        else:
            p2=p2-40

    return last_scores

print(game())
```

Comment: i only did not understand this. In my first code i started the p value with both players having 100. When i iterate im actually adding or subtracting those values. The current value in these cases are not the last scores?

Comment: No, the while loop is actually evaluated after the condition is reached, which means when player1 and player2 have reached negative values, then the while loop breaks, which leads you to get negative values, another way to solve this is using a white True loop, and breaking via if condition, in which case you won't need to remember last scores

Answer (score 0):

Change the while condition to:

```
while p1>0 and p2>0 and p1<200 and p2<200
```

but it is more readable if:

```
while 0<p1<200 and 0<p2<200
```

Comment: but with that sentence im assuming that those four conditions have to be met simultaneasly and that should be or not be the case

Comment: That is right. the game will end in four ways: `p1` goes below 0, `p2` goes below zero, `p1` goes above 200 and `p2` goes above 200. so until all of those 4 conditions stay. the game will go on.